# How to use correctly the return value from std::cin.get() and std::cin.peek()?

Tags: c++, iostream, peek

I've been always using `peek(), get()` this way:

```
int main(){

    std::string str;
    int value{};
    if(std::isdigit(std::cin.peek()))
       std::cin >> value;
    else
       std::getline(cin, str);

    std::cout << "value : " << value << '\n';
    std::cout << "str: " << str << '\n';

}
```

And many C++ websites and forums using such a thing:

```
while(std::cin.peek() != '\n)
    ; do somthing
```

- But after reading the note on C++ primer I am confused. It is said that those functions `get(), peek()` return an `int` not a `char` so we mustn't assign the result into a char but into an `int`.
- It is said there that Characters are converted first to `unsigned char` then promoted to `int`.

So how could I uses these functions correctly?

Comment: Internally, `peek` calls [`char_traits<char>::to_int_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/to_int_type) to convert the `char` value read from the stream to `int`.  People have been writing code like yours since forever, but I am surprised by the fact that I'm unable to find a requirement in the standard that guarantees `to_int_type('\n') == int('\n')`, for example.  I sincerely hope I'm wrong - certainly I don't want to have to write `using Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Traits::eq_int_type(std::cin.peek(), Traits::to_int_type('\n'))` each time.

Comment: The original code is poor as it consumes a whole line in one branch and a partial line in the other branch, so impossible to do the next piece of input correctly

Comment: @L.F.: Your comment is so useful. Please add an answer.

Comment: @Maestro I posted it as a question: [Is it guaranteed that std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c) == static_cast<int>(c)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66217741/9716597)

Answer (score 1):

> so we mustn't assign the result into a char but into an int

`while(std::cin.peek() != '\n')` is not assigning the result of `peek()` to a char. It is comparing a char and an int. Here the char is implicitly converted to an int and then compared. Thanks to @M.M, it is safer to use it this way: `while(std::cin.good() && std::cin.peek() != '\n')`

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/implicit-type-conversion-coercion/

Comment: The usage is not fine, as it gives an infinite loop if the input has an error

Comment: That makes no difference "It is just comparing a char and an int" because in both cases the character compared-to or assigned-to will be promoted to `int`.

Comment: If "it is just fine" then why `peek()` and `get()` return `int` rather than `char`? The standard library implementers are wise enough because there's no way to return from those function an end-of-file as a char. Because its value is out of range of characters. Assigning that value which is out of range of char to a signed char causes Overflowing a Singed Char which is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @M.M: Could you explain more?

Comment: @Maestro if the call returns EOF, how will the loop ever end?