# Is it guaranteed that std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c) == static_cast<int>(c)?

Tags: c++, io, language-lawyer, istream, char-traits

The question [How to use correctly the return value from `std::cin.get()` and `std::cin.peek()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66201757/9716597) made me wonder if it is guaranteed that

```cpp
std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c) == static_cast<int>(c)
```

for all valid `char` values `c`.

---

This comes up in a lot of places.  For example, `istream::peek` calls `streambuf::sgetc`, which uses `to_int_type` to convert the `char` value into `int_type`.  Now, does `std::cin.peek() == '\n'` really mean that the next character is `\n`?

---

Here's my analysis.  Let's collect the pieces from [[char.traits.require]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/char.traits.require) and [[char.traits.specializations.char]](http://%5Bchar.traits.specializations.char%5D):

1. For every `int` value `e`, `to_char_type(e)` returns

   - `c`, if `​eq_­int_­type(e, ​to_­int_­type(c))` for some `c`;
   - some unspecified value otherwise.
2. For every pair of `int` values `e` and `f`, `eq_­int_­type(e, f)` returns

   - `eq(c, d)`, if `e == to_int_type(c)` and `f == to_int_type(d)` for some `c` and `d`;
   - `true`, if `e == eof()` and `f == eof()`;
   - `false`, if `e == eof()` xor `f == eof()`;
   - unspecified otherwise.
3. `eof()` returns a value `e` such that `!eq_int_type(e, to_int_type(c))` for all `c`.
4. `eq(c, d)` iff `(unsigned char) c == (unsigned char) d`.

Now, consider this hypothetical implementation: (syntactically simplified)

```cpp
//          char: [-128, 127]
// unsigned char: [0, 255]
//           int: [-2^31, 2^31-1]

#define EOF INT_MIN

char to_char_type(int e) {
    return char(e - 1);
}

int to_int_type(char c) {
    return int(c) + 1;
}

bool eq(char c, char d) {
    return c == d;
}

bool eq_int_type(int c, int d) {
    return c == d;
}

int eof() {
    return EOF;
}
```

Note that

- (property 1) the conversion from `unsigned char` to `int` is value-preserving;
- (property 2) the conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` is bijective.

Now let's verify the requirements:

1. For every `int` value `e`, if `​eq_­int_­type(e, ​to_­int_­type(c))` for some `c`, then `e == int(c) + 1`.  Therefore, `to_char_type(e) == char(int(c)) == c`.
2. For every pair of `int` values `e` and `f`, if `e == to_int_type(c)` and `f == to_int_type(d)` for some `c` and `d`, then `eq_int_type(e, f)` iff `int(c) + 1 == int(d) + 1` iff `c == d` (by property 1).  The EOF cases are also trivially verifiable.
3. For every `char` value `c`, `int(c) >= -128`, so `int(c) + 1 != EOF`.  Therefore, `!eq_int_type(eof(), to_int_type(c))`.
4. For every pair of `char` values `c` and `d`, `eq(c, d)` iff `(unsigned char) c == (unsigned char d)` (by property 2).

Does that mean this implementation is conforming, and therefore `std::cin.peek() == '\n'` does not do what it is supposed to do?  Did I miss anything in my analysis?

Comment: Not guaranteed, and in fact the two are [often different](https://godbolt.org/z/Md4xYe) with typical implementations.

Comment: For what it's worth, my reading is the same as yours; `to_int_type` is allowed to perform any reversible transformation, nothing says that `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c) == static_cast<int>(c)` must hold for any value of `c`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik At least `char` values that fit in `unsigned char` don't seem to deviate with common implementations - now I have to count the amount of `peek() == '\n'` that I have written! (*shrug*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean this implementation is conforming, and therefore std::cin.peek() == '\n' does not do what it is supposed to do?

I agree with your analysis. This isn't guaranteed.

It appears that you would have to use `eq_­int_­type(std::cin.peek(), ​to_­int_­type('\n'))` to guarantee correct result.

---

P.S. Your `​to_­char_­type(EOF)` has undefined behaviour due to signed overflow in `INT_MIN - 1`. Sure, the value is unspecified in this case, but you still cannot have UB. This would be valid:

```
char to_char_type(int e) {
    return e == EOF
         ? 0 // doesn't matter
         : char(e - 1);
}
```

`to_int_type` would have UB on systems where int and char are same size in case `c == INT_MAX`, but you've excluded those systems with the hypothetical sizes.